# Moment of inertia of stuffed cylinder

Tags: rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

How might I find the moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder (of non-negligible thickness) that has had a sponge stuffed inside of it? I know the mass and volume of the sponge and suppose I would assume the sponge has constant density inside the cylinder, but how exactly would I integrate over the two radii using that sponge density to find the total moment of inertia?

Comment: A drawing would help.  Also, the weight of the sponge, and the volume of the sponge while it is inside the cylinder would help.

Comment: Moment of inertia about the cylinder axis?

Comment: You can simply add up the momenta, see parallel axis theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take concentric rings of thickness ${\rm d}r$, length $\ell$ and see how mass and mass moment of inertia develop from the center.

1. **Sponge Domain** $r=0 \ldots R_I$

   - $ m_S = \int \limits_0^{R_I} \rho_{S} (2 \pi r \ell) {\rm d}r $
   - $ I_S = \int \limits_0^{R_I} \rho_{S}\, r^2 (2 \pi r \ell) {\rm d} r$
2. **Tube Domain** $r = R_I \ldots R_O$

   - $ m_T = \int \limits_{R_I}^{R_O} \rho_{T} (2 \pi r \ell) {\rm d}r $
   - $ I_T = \int \limits_{R_I}^{R_O} \rho_{T}\, r^2 (2 \pi r \ell) {\rm d} r$

Combined mass is $m = m_S +m_T$ and combined mass moment of inertia $I = I_S + I_T$.

So if you know that mass of each part you evaluate the above as:

1. **Sponge Domain**

   - $ \rho_S = \frac{m_S}{\ell \pi R_I^2} $
   - $ I_S = \left( \frac{m_S}{2} \right) R_I^2 $
2. **Tube Domain**

   - $ \rho_T = \frac{m_T}{\ell \pi ( R_O^2-R_I^2)} $
   - $ I_T = \left( \frac{m_T}{2} \right) (R_O^2+R_I^2)$

That final $+$ sign, is not a typo. If the mass is known then the mass moment of inertia is proportional to $R_O^2+R_I^2$.

The total mass moment of inertia is thus

$$\boxed{ I = \left( \frac{m_S}{2} \right) R_I^2 + \left( \frac{m_T}{2} \right) (R_O^2+R_I^2) }$$